# buttons within a div

Tags: php, css, html, dynamic

I know a little bit of PHP already but I can not get this to work. I was hoping that by using opencart CMS I would learn some more basic PHP but now I Am really stuck.

This code should make some uploadbuttons appear on the page. The thing is, though. I would like them to appear in a DIV so I can float the buttons next to each other using CSS.

Here is the code:

```
<?php if ($option['type'] == 'file') { ?>
    <div id="option-<?php echo $option['product_option_id']; ?>" class="upload" >
      <?php if ($option['required']) { ?>
      <span class="required">*</span>

      <?php } ?>
      <b><?php echo $option['name']; ?>:</b><br />
      <input type="button" value="<?php echo $button_upload; ?>" id="button option-<?php echo $option['product_option_id']; ?>" class="button">
      <input type="hidden" name="option[<?php echo $option['product_option_id']; ?>]" value="" />
    </div>
```

Could anyone tell me how to accomplish this or point me in the right direction?

Comment: Why not just do `<div> <input type="button" ...> </div>` ?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php if ($option['type'] == 'file') { // You didn't close your bracket. 
// Insert code here
}
 ?>
    <div id="option-<?php echo $option['product_option_id']; ?>" class="upload" >
      <?php if ($option['required']) {// Again here. ?>
      <span class="required">*</span>

      <?php } ?>
      <b><?php echo $option['name']; ?>:</b><br />
      <input type="button" value="<?php echo $button_upload; ?>" id="button option-<?php echo $option['product_option_id']; ?>" class="button">
      <input type="hidden" name="option[<?php echo $option['product_option_id']; ?>]" value="" />
    </div>
```

Comment: I don't see the problem, could you be more specific?